# How is P not trivially equal to ZPP?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-classes, randomized-algorithms

The definition of ZPP seems to be

$$ZPP = RP \cap coRP.$$

I think ZPP should then be equivalent to P, because for any language L in ZPP, there is an algorithm A and B proving that it is in RP and coRP, respectively. Since A must tell for any x s.t. $x \notin L$ the truth and B for any x s.t. $x \notin L$ as well, we can just run both algorithms in polynomial time, and one of them has to give me the answer since these are the only two possible options.

Is there an error in my thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in your reasoning. Say that $x \not\in L$. Then when you run $A(x)$ you'll get a "no" answer with certainty. However, when you run $B(x)$ you'll get a "no" with some probability that can be up to $1/2$.

What do you do when both $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ return "no"? In order to answer correctly you'd need to return "no".

Consider now $x \in L$. $A(x)$ will return "no" with some probability that can be up to $1/2$, while $B(x)$ will return "no" with certainty. We already argued that you algorithm returns "no" in this case, but this is incorrect.

Comment: Nice explanation, but is also worth mentioning that the particular error in the reasoning is that "and one of them has to give me the answer since these are the only two possible options." is simply wrong; both give answers, and you know that one of them must be correct but you don't know which one. This is trivial as you can replace them by $\Sigma^\star$ and $\varnothing$.

Comment: Yeah. There are $3$ possible combinations of the two answers. If $x \in L$ you get one of $\{(yes, no), (no, no)\}$. If $x \not\in L$ you get one of $\{ (no, yes), (no, no) \}$. If you you need to decide  $x \in L$ and you observe the output of $A$ and $B$ then you can answer correctly when you see either $(yes, no)$ or $(no, yes)$. However, the answers $(no, no)$ are inconclusive (or, if you wish, you don't know which of the two algorithms was incorrect).